# Conversion constructor between classes c++

Tags: c++, class

The background: I am reading a wonderful book, where they briefly mentioned conversion constructors.

Though I understand fundamentals of the conversion constructors, I was a bit lost, when in practice problems section they asked:

Write a conversion constractor that converts `ratnum` into `realnum` from the code that I received prior to the problem:

```
class ratnum {
    int num, denom;
public:
    ratnum(int numenator = 2, int denominator = 3) : num(numenator), denom(denominator) {}
    void show() { cout << static_cast<double>(num) / denom << endl; }
    double result() { return num / denom; }

};

class realnum {
    int number;
public:
    realnum(double numr = 0) : number (numr) {}
};
```

I always dealt with the conversion constructors as such:

```
ratnum one = 10; //or
ratnum two = {10, 2}
```

But never saw that we can convert from class to a class type. 
Could you, please, say how such conversion constructor should work (maybe with example)?

Is defining a function `result` of the `ratnum` class and writing:

```
realnum check = one.result();
```

is what is meant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what they meant is that there is an overload of the constructor that takes an input of the other class, for example

```
realnum(ratnum const& other) : number{other.result()} {}
```

And vice-versa to construct a `ratnum` from a `realnum`, although that could be less trivial as there are irrational numbers, infinitely repeating numbers, etc.

You could use this version of the constructor to do something like

```
ratnum a{2, 4};
realnum b{a};    // This used your "conversion" constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

> But never saw that we can convert from class to a class type. Could
>   you, please, say how such conversion constructor should work (maybe
>   with example)?

It's exactly the same as converting from a non-class type. There's literally absolutely no difference at all.